# htacces cat/subcategory show subcategory.php page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following path:

```
Root
--cp
----cursos-de-ingles.php
----ingles-general.php
----course-details.php
```

I have the following htacces rule:

```
RewriteRule ^cursos-de-ingles  cp/cursos-de-ingles.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cursos-de-ingles/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

if I navegate to /cursos-de-ingles I see the cursos-de-ingles.php with the list of course
if I go to /cursos-de-ingles/nombre-de-curso I see the course-details.php?name=nombre-de-curso with the information of the course

And this is what I want, but now I have a sub category inside the /cursos-de-ingles, so I need the a htaccess rule to accomplish the following:

If I go to /cursos-de-ingles/subcategory/ I need to see the ingles-general.php page with the list of course in this category.

Also if I go to /cursos-de-ingles/subcategory/nombre-de-curso I need to see the course-details.php?name=nombre-de-curso with the information of the course

I was trying something like this:

RewriteRule ^cursos-de-ingles/ingles-general/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]

and this works perfect I see the course-details.php?name=nombre-de-curso with the correct information.

But when I go to /cursos-de-ingles/ingles-general I see the course-details.php?name=ingles-general with out information, because "ingles-general" is no a course name is a subcategory and it suppose to show me the ingles-general.php page.

this is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^cursos-de-ingles/ingles-general  cp/ingles-general.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+) cp/ingles-general.php?name=$1&sub=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/ingles-general cp/ingles-general.php?name=$1&sub=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)/$ /ingles-general.php?name=$1&sub=$2 [NC,L]
```

but nothing works.

Help pelase

Comment: How do you expect it know the difference between `/cursos-de-ingles/ingles-general` and `/cursos-de-ingles/anythingelse`, the current rule you have will match both. You need another way to differientiate your subcategory

Comment: @PanamaJack thanks for your anwser, I though this could be impossible, but I need to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^cursos-de-ingles  cp/cursos-de-ingles.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cursos-de-ingles/ingles-general  cp/ingles-general.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^cursos-de-ingles/(?!ingles-general)([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cursos-de-ingles/ingles-general/([^/]+)/?$ cp/course-details.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```